# adding array contents into a csv file

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I've scoured many sites trying to resolve my issue, but most answers is related to using a single array.
I'm trying to read 2x text files. Each file is filled with multiple csv lines.
From these two files do I search and select very specific information.
My aim to then to write a single CSV file filled with info I selected.
I've achieved reading the 2x input files. I managed to get my selected specific data.
How I captured the data was to use arrays.
I effectively read up to max of 64x values per parameter. There is approx 20x such parameters.

as an example, I do this by using:

```
parameter1[counter]
parameters2[counter] etc
```

All 20x parameters values are related to one another and this is what the counter value ensures.

What I need to do with these captured values is to write a csv file.
Every line (up to 64x max) should contains 20x parameters.

So, expected results should be:

```
para1-1,para2-1,para3-1,para4-1,,,,,
para1-2,para2-2,para3-2,para4-2,,,,,
etc.
```

Here is some code to show what I've done:

```
vall="Value="
write1count=1
recallcount=1

# functions here

read1_function() {
 exec 8<$file1
            while read -r cap1in <&$FD1
             do
 if [[ "$maccount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    mac_function
    fi
 if [[ "$antcount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    ant_function
    fi
 if [[ "$namecount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    name_function
    fi
let count++
done < "$file1"
}

mac_function() {
 macvariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.12."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$macvariable* ]]; then
   let maccount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$macvariable$maccount* ]]; then
     macaddress[maccount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

ant_function() {
 antvariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.6."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$antvariable* ]]; then
   let antcount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$antvariable$antcount* ]]; then
     antconf[antcount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

name_function() {
 namevariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.4."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$namevariable* ]]; then
   let namecount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$namevariable$namecount* ]]; then
     nameconf[namecount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

# step is to create export file containing all customer config
 exec 6>$file3   #open file3 to dump new config in

 while [ $recallcount -lt 65 ]; do
 echo recall $recallcount
  if [[ "${macaddress[recallcount]}" == *:* ]]; then
   echo $write1count,2,1,${macaddress[recallcount]},${antconf[recallcount]},${nameconf[recallcount]} >>$file3

exec 6>&-
echo "Job completed"
exit
```

However, I don't get the desired results.

Comment: No wonder that you _don't get the desired results_ when you use `do` without `done` and `ìf` without `fi`.

Comment: Paste your code in at shellcheck.net; fix anything it complains about.

Comment: Please post sample input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Armali.....
I included some copy/paste from my code.
I left some parts out....now added at end....

some sample info:

```
macaddress[recallcount]=00:12:23:45:67:89
antconf[recallcount]=2
nameconf[recallcount]=customername
```

.

```
vall="Value="
write1count=1
recallcount=1

# functions here

read1_function() {
 exec 8<$file1
            while read -r cap1in <&$FD1
             do
 if [[ "$maccount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    mac_function
    fi
 if [[ "$antcount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    ant_function
    fi
 if [[ "$namecount" -lt 65 ]]; then
    name_function
    fi
let count++
done < "$file1"
}

mac_function() {
 macvariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.12."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$macvariable* ]]; then
   let maccount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$macvariable$maccount* ]]; then
     macaddress[maccount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

ant_function() {
 antvariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.6."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$antvariable* ]]; then
   let antcount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$antvariable$antcount* ]]; then
     antconf[antcount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

name_function() {
 namevariable="OID=.1000.3.1.6.2.1.4."
 if [[ "$cap1in" == *$namevariable* ]]; then
   let namecount++
   if [[ "$cap1in" == *$namevariable$namecount* ]]; then
     nameconf[namecount]=${cap1in#*$vall}
  fi
 fi
 }

# step is to create export file containing all customer config
 exec 6>$file3   #open file3 to dump new config in

 while [ $recallcount -lt 65 ]; do
 echo recall $recallcount
  if [[ "${macaddress[recallcount]}" == *:* ]]; then
   echo $write1count,2,1,"${macaddress[recallcount]}","${antconf[recallcount]}","${nameconf[recallcount]}" >>$file3

  echo writecount $write1count
  let write1count++
  fi

 let recallcount++;
 done

exec 6>&-
echo "Job completed"
exit
```

end result with above:

```
 ,customername
```

Comment: The problem is related to the echo command writing the strings to the csv file. Instead of using the proposed : echo $write1count,2,1,"${macaddress[recallcount]}","${antconf[recallcount]}","${nameconf[recallcount]}" If I use echo $write1count echo 2 echo 1 echo "${macaddress[recallcount]}" then everything is captured correctly as expected ....however without the required ","